# java.sql.SQLSyntaxError at INSERT Statement

Tags: java, sql, insert, hsqldb

I am currently filling my hsql db with an insert Statement, but it doesn`t work and I cannot see the mistake...

here are my INSERT statements:

```
INSERT INTO Waren VALUES(name, kategorie, geloescht, haltbar, preis, altersfreigabe) VALUES
('Schnitzel', 'Speisen', FALSE, 'TRUE', 1.20, 0);
INSERT INTO Waren VALUES('Apfel', 'Speisen', FALSE, 'TRUE', 2.00, 0);
INSERT INTO Waren VALUES ('Kokosnüsse', 'Speisen', FALSE, 'TRUE', 1.00, 0);
INSERT INTO Waren VALUES('Suppe', 'Speisen', FALSE, 'TRUE', 2.00, 0);
INSERT INTO Waren VALUES('Karotte', 'Speisen', FALSE, 'TRUE', 1.00, 0);
INSERT INTO Waren VALUES('Kaiserschmarn', 'Speisen', FALSE, 'TRUE', 2.90, 0);
INSERT INTO Waren VALUES('Schnaps', 'Getraenke', FALSE, 'TRUE', 2.90, 18);
INSERT INTO Waren VALUES('Cola Rum', 'Getraenke', FALSE, 'TRUE', 2.70, 18);
INSERT INTO Waren VALUES('Wein', 'Getraenke', FALSE, 'TRUE', 1.20, 18);
INSERT INTO Waren VALUES('Bier', 'Getraenke', FALSE, 'TRUE', 3.00, 16);
INSERT INTO Waren VALUES('Dead Killer Drink', 'Getraenke', FALSE, 'TRUE', 7.00, 18);
```

I appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the first `VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO Waren (name, kategorie, geloescht, haltbar, preis, altersfreigabe) VALUES
('Schnitzel', 'Speisen', FALSE, 'TRUE', 1.20, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a VALUES too much.

```
INSERT INTO Waren **VALUES**(name, kategorie, ...
```

should be removed.